# Changing the speed of an animation in an Android app

Tags: android, android-animation, android-constraintlayout

I need to modify the speed of an animation, reacting to some events in an app of mine. To tackle the problem I made a small demo app. I hope someone can give me some guidance on how to change the code to get what I want. When one taps on the label the background color toggles, but the speed should also change; and this is precisely my question.

Here is the code for the app:

```
package me.software.myapp

import .....

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var constrLayout:ConstraintLayout? = null
    private var appLabel:TextView? = null
    private var labelBG:View? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        constrLayout = findViewById(R.id.main)
        animateView()
    }


    fun animateView() {
        val mainFrameID = resources.getIdentifier("main","id",packageName)
        val constrSet = ConstraintSet(); val otherConstrSet = ConstraintSet()

        appLabel = TextView(this)
        appLabel?.id = View.generateViewId()
        appLabel?.text = "ANDROID&LINUX"

        setLabelBG()

        appLabel?.setOnClickListener {
            println("appLabel-HIT-appLabel")
            if (labelBG?.visibility == View.VISIBLE) labelBG?.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            else labelBG?.visibility = View.VISIBLE

            // I need to do something to change the speed.
            // For instance, if the the animation had 8 seconds left, I want to speed it up and finish in 4 seconds.
        }

        constrLayout?.addView(appLabel)

        constrSet.clone(constrLayout)
        constrSet.connect(appLabel!!.id, ConstraintSet.LEFT, mainFrameID, ConstraintSet.LEFT)
        constrSet.connect(appLabel!!.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, mainFrameID, ConstraintSet.TOP)
        constrSet.applyTo(constrLayout)

        otherConstrSet.clone(constrLayout)
        otherConstrSet.clear(appLabel!!.id, ConstraintSet.LEFT)
        otherConstrSet.clear(appLabel!!.id, ConstraintSet.TOP)
        otherConstrSet.connect(appLabel!!.id, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, mainFrameID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT)
        otherConstrSet.connect(appLabel!!.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, mainFrameID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)

        constrLayout?.post {
            val autoTransition = AutoTransition()
            autoTransition.setDuration(10000)
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(constrLayout, autoTransition)
            otherConstrSet.applyTo(constrLayout);
        }
    }


    fun setLabelBG() {
        labelBG = View(this)
        labelBG?.id =  View.generateViewId()
        labelBG?.elevation = -1F
        constrLayout?.addView(labelBG)
        val constrSet = ConstraintSet();
        labelBG?.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0xFF,0xFF,0x00))
        constrSet.connect(labelBG!!.id, ConstraintSet.LEFT, appLabel!!.id, ConstraintSet.LEFT)
        constrSet.connect(labelBG!!.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, appLabel!!.id, ConstraintSet.TOP)
        constrSet.connect(labelBG!!.id, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, appLabel!!.id, ConstraintSet.RIGHT)
        constrSet.connect(labelBG!!.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, appLabel!!.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)
        constrSet.applyTo(constrLayout)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following is your code:

```
constrLayout?.post {
        val autoTransition = AutoTransition()
        autoTransition.setDuration(10000)
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(constrLayout, autoTransition)
        otherConstrSet.applyTo(constrLayout);
    }
```

Try changing the autoTransition duration as less as possible to get the speed you need.

```
autoTransition.setDuration(5000)
```

Comment: Thank you, but that does not answer the question. My question is about "changing the speed" and not "setting the speed". It is set on purpose to 10000 at start and I want it to change to 5000 when the label is clicked (maybe in appLabel?.setOnClickListener{...} but I am not sure how to do it. The animation should run faster after I tap the label.